# Truncate all files in a directory after underscore?

Tags: shell, rename, sed, awk, batch-rename

I have a directory with a couple thousand images in it. Most of them have sensible filenames like SD-000.tif SD-001.tif BX-000.tif etc...

However probably ~25% of them have names like BX-003_old.tif BX-004_veryold.tif

How can I rename the problem files by removing the _word from the end of the each?

The files are stored on a FreeBSD server however the directory is shared out via samba.

I tried using combinations of sed and awk but I'm not having any luck getting them to only work with the middle of the files.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
newname=${filename%_*}.${filename##*.}
```

`${filename%_*}`  gives the part before the last underscore.
`${filename##*.}`  gives you the part after the last dot (the extension).

Comment: In case anyone ever ends up having a similar problem in the future I ended up fixing this with the cut command.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone ever ends up having a similar problem in the future I ended up fixing this with the cut command.
I ran:

```
for i in *
do
mv $i `echo $i|cut -d"_" -f1`
done
```

The loop simply selects all files in the current directory and the cut -d specifies to truncate everything after the specified character. In my case the _.

Comment: You don't care about the file's extension?